# Stop an animating UIScrollView when another UIScrollView is scrolled

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uianimation, swift2

Let's say I've multiple scroll views and I want only one of them to be open (`scrollView.contentOffset != 0`) at any given time. So, when `scroll view 1` is open and `scroll view 2` is scrolled, `scroll view 1` should animate to close. The problem occurs when I quickly open `scroll view 1` and `scroll view 2`; when this happens `scroll view 1` is still decelerating and `scroll view 2`'s opening tries to force `scroll view 1` to close and breaks the animations and sometimes does not close.
One way to solve this would be to disable scrolling until a scroll view finishes decelerating. But, I'm looking for other solutions which handle this problem more seamlessly.
I've tried `scrollView.layer.removeAllAnimations()`. This does not stop the decelerating animation. I want the animations of `scroll view 1` to stop instantly when `scroll view 2` is scrolled and then `scroll view 1` can be animated to `contentOffset = 0`.

> Identify if `scroll view` is opening or closing.

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    scrollView.bounces = scrollView.contentOffset.x > 20
    if scrollView.contentOffset.x < self.lastContentOffset && scrollView.contentOffset.x < 70 {
        ifOpening = false
    }
    else if scrollView.contentOffset.x > 5 {
        ifOpening = true
    }
    self.lastContentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.x

}
```

> When a `scroll view` is dragged close all other `scroll view`'s.

```
func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    for eachScrollView in taskArrayScrollView{
        if  eachScrollView != scrollView {
            eachScrollView.layer.removeAllAnimations()
            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2,
                delay: 0.5,
                options: .CurveEaseIn ,
                animations: { eachScrollView.contentOffset.x = 0 },
                completion: nil
            )
        }
    }
}
```

> To snap the `scroll view` to either `offset` 0 or 70

```
func scrollViewDidEndDragging(scrollViewa: UIScrollView, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool) {
    let intialContentOffset = scrollViewa.contentOffset.x
    var originalContentOffset: CGFloat
    var finalContentOffset: CGFloat
    var minOffset: CGFloat

    if intialContentOffset == boundOfScreen.width{
        return
    }

    if ifOpening{
        minOffset = 20.0
        originalContentOffset = 0
        finalContentOffset = 70
    }

    else {
        minOffset = 50.0
        originalContentOffset = 0
        finalContentOffset = 70
    }

    if (!decelerate){
        if intialContentOffset < minOffset {
            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2,
                delay: 0.1,
                options: .CurveEaseIn ,
                animations: { scrollViewa.contentOffset.x = originalContentOffset },
                completion: {
                    finished in scrollViewa.userInteractionEnabled = true
                }
            )
        }
        else {
            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2,
                delay: 0.1,
                options: .CurveEaseIn ,
                animations: { scrollViewa.contentOffset.x = finalContentOffset },
                completion: {
                    finished in scrollViewa.userInteractionEnabled = true
                }
            )
        }
    }
}


func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(scrollViewb: UIScrollView) {
    let intialContentOffset = scrollViewb.contentOffset.x
    var originalContentOffset: CGFloat
    var finalContentOffset: CGFloat
    var minOffset: CGFloat
    //println("intialContentOffset: \(intialContentOffset)")

    if ifOpening{
        minOffset = 20.0
        originalContentOffset = 0
        finalContentOffset = 70
        //println("dec: opening")
    }

    else {
        minOffset = 50.0
        originalContentOffset = 0
        finalContentOffset = 70
        //println("dec: closing")
    }


    if intialContentOffset < minOffset {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2,
            delay: 0.1,
            options: .CurveEaseIn ,
            animations: {scrollViewb.contentOffset.x = originalContentOffset },
            completion: {
                finished in scrollViewb.userInteractionEnabled = true
            }
        )
    }
    else {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2,
            delay: 0.1,
            options: .CurveEaseIn ,
            animations: {scrollViewb.contentOffset.x = finalContentOffset },
            completion: {
                finished in scrollViewb.userInteractionEnabled = true
            }

        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well... I found a work around. I used a variable `viewOpenCounter` to keep track if another `scroll view` is opened, and if it is, then close the currently animating `scroll view` after it finishes animating. Not sure if this is efficient.

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    scrollView.bounces = scrollView.contentOffset.x > 20

    if scrollView.contentOffset.x < self.lastContentOffset && scrollView.contentOffset.x < 70 {
        isOpening = false
    }
    else if scrollView.contentOffset.x > 5 {
        isOpening = true
        viewOpenCounter = true
    }
    self.lastContentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.x
}

func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if !viewOpenCounter {
        for eachScrollView in taskArrayScrollView {
            if  eachScrollView != scrollView {
                UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2,
                    delay: 0.5,
                    options: .CurveEaseIn ,
                    animations: { eachScrollView.contentOffset.x = 0 },
                    completion: nil
                )}
        }
    }
}
 func scrollViewDidEndDragging(scrollViewa: UIScrollView, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool) {

    viewOpenCounter = false

    let intialContentOffset = scrollViewa.contentOffset.x
    var originalContentOffset: CGFloat
    var finalContentOffset: CGFloat
    var minOffset: CGFloat

    if intialContentOffset == boundOfScreen.width{
        return
    }

    if isOpening{
        minOffset = 20.0
        originalContentOffset = 0
        finalContentOffset = 70
    }

    else {
        minOffset = 50.0
        originalContentOffset = 0
        finalContentOffset = 70
    }

    if (!decelerate){
        //println("no dec \(intialContentOffset)")

        if intialContentOffset < minOffset {
            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2,
                delay: 0.1,
                options: .CurveEaseIn ,
                animations: { scrollViewa.contentOffset.x = originalContentOffset },
                completion: {
                    finished in scrollViewa.userInteractionEnabled = true
                    if self.viewOpenCounter {
                        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, animations: {
                            scrollViewa.contentOffset.x = 0
                        },
                            completion: {
                                finished in
                                self.viewOpenCounter = false
                            }
                        )
                    }
                }
            )
        }
        else {
            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2,
                delay: 0.1,
                options: .CurveEaseIn ,
                animations: { scrollViewa.contentOffset.x = finalContentOffset },
                completion: {
                    finished in scrollViewa.userInteractionEnabled = true
                    if self.viewOpenCounter {
                        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, animations: {
                            scrollViewa.contentOffset.x = 0

                        },
                            completion: {
                                finished in
                                self.viewOpenCounter = false
                            }
                        )
                    }
                }
            )
        }
    }
}

 func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(scrollViewb: UIScrollView) {

    viewOpenCounter = false

    let intialContentOffset = scrollViewb.contentOffset.x
    var originalContentOffset: CGFloat
    var finalContentOffset: CGFloat
    var minOffset: CGFloat
    //println("intialContentOffset: \(intialContentOffset)")

    if isOpening{
        minOffset = 20.0
        originalContentOffset = 0
        finalContentOffset = 70
        //println("dec: opening")
    }

    else {
        minOffset = 50.0
        originalContentOffset = 0
        finalContentOffset = 70
        //println("dec: closing")
    }


    if intialContentOffset < minOffset {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2,
            delay: 0.1,
            options: .CurveEaseIn ,
            animations: {scrollViewb.contentOffset.x = originalContentOffset },
            completion: {
                finished in scrollViewb.userInteractionEnabled = true
                if self.viewOpenCounter {
                    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, animations: {
                        scrollViewb.contentOffset.x = 0
                    },
                        completion: {
                            finished in
                            self.viewOpenCounter = false
                        }
                    )
                }
            }
        )
    }
    else {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2,
            delay: 0.1,
            options: .CurveEaseIn ,
            animations: {scrollViewb.contentOffset.x = finalContentOffset },
            completion: {
                finished in scrollViewb.userInteractionEnabled = true
                if self.viewOpenCounter {
                    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, animations: {
                        scrollViewb.contentOffset.x = 0
                    },
                        completion: {
                            finished in
                            self.viewOpenCounter = false
                        }
                    )
                }
            }

        )
    }
}
```